# Should I use 'of' or not? "Plays of Shakespeare" vs "Shakespeare's plays"

Tags: prepositions, possessives

When should one use the following one over another?

- **The plays of Shakespeare** will always be classics.
- **Shakespeare's plays** will always be classics.

Answer (score 1):

It is a 'rule of thumb' found in many English textbooks that one should use possessive nouns for living things and "*of*" for inanimate objects.

For example:

**Living things/people:**

- My wife's sister
- The dog's bed

**Inanimate objects:**

- The bottom of the stairs
- The foot of the bed

Following this "rule" would mean "Shakespeare's plays" is the *preferred option*, although it doesn't mean that the alternative is not correct. "The plays of Shakespeare" is an often-cited example to disprove this rule of thumb, however [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Shakespeare%27s%20plays%2C%20the%20plays%20of%20Shakespeare&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CShakespeare%20%27s%20plays%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20plays%20of%20Shakespeare%3B%2Cc0) shows that it is the most widely used of the two.

Comment: By "most widely used", do you mean "*less* widely used"?   (The ngram appears to show that "the plays of Shakespeare" is less widely used than "Shakespeare's plays".)